# Live data on QGIS Cloud?

Tags: qgis, python, excel, qgis-python-console

I have a line layer that is rulebased labeled to show green segments and red segments based on 'status' attribute.

Currently, I download data from an excel sheet on sharepoint as a csv and then import it to qgis and create a join. Finally I'll save the new shapefile in postgis and publish on qgiscloud.

Is there a way to scrape the excel data on sharepoint and have qgis cloud prject the changes live?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with qgiscloud, I think you should be able to add the excel file as a table, and use virtual layers to create and display the join. This would be dependent on the qgiscloud having access to both the original shapefile and the excel file.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Brian. I am not so much concerned about how to join data from a CSV but rather how to scrape a excel sheet from a website and connect it to the qgis layer so the web map updates automatically.